# Does Crafter's Fortune negate Pugwampi Unluck?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters

The Pugwampi's Unluck Aura reads:

> A pugwampi radiates an aura of unluck to a radius of 20 feet. Any creature in this area must roll two d20s whenever a situation calls for a d20 roll (such as an attack roll, a skill check, or a saving throw) and must use the lower of the two results generated. This is a mind-affecting effect that does not work on animals, other gremlins, or gnolls. Any character who gains any sort of luck bonus (such as that granted by a luckstone or divine favor) is immune to the pugwampi unluck aura.

Crafter's Fortune reads:

> The target is struck by inspiration and gains a +5 luck bonus on its next Craft skill check.

Is the target of Crafter's Fortune immune for the duration of the spell?

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this interpreted as "if you have a luck bonus on your roll, you don't suffer the aura for that roll." With this interpretation, Crafter's Fortune don't make you immune to the aura.

Of course, as the rules are ambiguous, it's up to the GM to make a decision, but this one seems fair to me.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at

> Any character who gains any sort of luck bonus (such as that granted by a luckstone or divine favor) is immune to the pugwampi unluck aura.

and

> The target is struck by inspiration and gains a +5 luck bonus on its next Craft skill check.

I would read "any sort of luck bonus" to mean "any sort of luck bonus *to the roll being made*".

So, the character would be immune to the unluck aura *on its next Craft skill check only.*

Comment: I would expect a luck bonus to anything to negate the aura for everything. It is not technically the same but pugwampis grace reads "As with the aura shed by actual pugwampies, this spell has no effect onanimals, gremlins, or gnolls. The effects of this spell are negated as long as a target gains any sort of luck bonus to a d20 roll (such as those granted by a luckstone ordivine favor), but the spell’s duration is not impacted by these effects. If the luck bonus goes away before the pugwampi’s grace effect ends, the unluck returns and remains until the spell’s normal duration runs out." Which